# Using NET_DNS2 Get records

Tags: php, dns, pear

I'm using pear package [NET_DNS2](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_DNS2/). I can get records using the code below. But i have some confusion about the nameserver 8.8.8.8. This is Google Public name server address. Why we are using this. And how can i change this to my own name server for local host.

```
<?php

require "NET/DNS2.php";

$r = new Net_DNS2_Resolver(array('nameservers' => array('8.8.8.8')));
$result = $r->query('domain.com', 'A');

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

How can i get Domain Owner and Hosting provider information. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NET_DNS2 communicate with the dns server by sending request from the specified nameserver.

You can use your own computer Ip address for this (Not 127.0.0.1 or localhost)

Answer (score 0):

> Why we are using this

Because it's fast, awesome and free*?

> And how can i change this to my own name server for local host.

Replace `'8.8.8.8'` with `'localhost'` or `'127.0.0.1'`, maybe?  C'mon man, show some effort.

<sup><sub>* There ain't no such thing as a free lunch; what's Google doing with our DNS queries?</sub></sup>

Comment: it will not work with the localhost or 127.0.0.1. I got it working with my IP address.

Comment: What do you mean "will not work"?

Answer (score 0):

You can leave out the `nameservers` option, and it will default to using the nameservers in `/etc/resolv.conf`, just like other network software on your system.